# Custom UISegmentedControl like the Scope control in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I like to create a UISegmentedControl that looks like the scope button in UISearchBar.

[image]

Do you know how to do it?

**Update:**
So I want to create a UISegmentedControl like this
(please notice the appearance), this is not related with UISearchBar,
I just want to make it LOOKS LIKE the scope buttons in UISearchBar.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mySegmentedBar.segmentedControlStyle = 7;
```

It's undocumented, but seems to pass App Store review.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding a `UISearchBar` and a `UIToolbar` with a `UISegmentedControl` in it to the view. You can do this in code or in Interface Builder.

Drag a `UISearchBar` out onto the view and align it to the top.

[image]

Add a `UIToolbar` and remove the button that comes on it.

[image: ToolBar]

Drag a `UISegmentedControl` onto the `UIToolbar`.

[image: UISegmentedControl]

Wire everything up to the properties in your h. If you want to change the look of the controls, you can modify the tint color of both the items to make them a more silver look or something completely different.

[image: Tinted Control]

Comment: No, I want to create UISegmentedControl (that looks like the scope bar in UISearchBar). I don't want to create a UISearchBar.

Comment: I updated my answer to illustrate changing UIToolbar and UISegmentedControl tint color. You can try to change the tint and text color until it matches the scope bar.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have direct access to the UISegmentedControl on a UISearchBar, so you will have to set the global appearance of the `UISegementedControl` using the UIAppearance protocol on the `UISearchBar`. See [Customizing Appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007529-CH3-SW40) in the documentation for `UISearchBar`.

To to set a background image for example use:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setScopeBarBackgroundImage:someImage];
```