# why IB sometimes doesn't add a subview to a view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

Sometimes IB simply doesn't allow you to add a view as a subview to a `UIViewController` as illustrated here [image]

If I drag a UIViewController from the object library and try to embed it within Mailbox View Controller.. it doesn't highlight, however it would work fine if I try to add it to the generic View Controller at the bottom (can the fact that Mailbox View Controller have a Customer Class *MailboxViewController* have anything to do with it?)

I'm pretty sure I can do this programmatically (which is what I'll try next) but I was wondering if there was a reason for this (and if there was a way around it).

**update:**
this is what i'm trying to accomplish: I was following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128659/766570) to implement a segmented view controller below search bar like in the iphone [mail app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169095/custom-uisegmentedcontrol-like-the-scope-control-in-uisearchbar).. however I kept on getting an error saying that a view can only belong to one view controller at a time.. So what I'm trying to do is basically create a separate viewcontroller, reference it from `MailboxViewController` as an outlet, make the containing view of my search area the view of this new view controller (this is where i'm getting stuck) and finally make the `searchContentsController` property of `UISearchDisplayController` refer to the view of this new view controller. (if this sounds confusing, which I know it does, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128659/766570))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, the `view` property of your mailbox view controller is a table view.

A table view in interface builder won't support the dropping of arbitrary views onto it as subviews - where would it put them at runtime? In IB the table has no content, it just has that visual representation of cells to let you know what it is.

You haven't said what you are trying to set up so I can't offer any additional help. Adding a subview programmatically to a table view probably won't give you the effect you're after either - a table view is a UIScrollView subclass, so your new view will either move off screen or get covered up by the table view adding cells.

Comment: Oh i think I get it now.. basically my `MailBoxViewController` is a subclass of `UITableViewController`.. so I should just make it a subclass of a generic `UIViewController` and do the rest of the work from there.. thanks!